# Having trouble accessing SAML Assertion during POST

Tags: servlets, keycloak, saml-2.0

I am trying to implement a SSO solution using keycloak (SAML) with the tomcat adapter.  I have created a user, realm and client.  I have even given the client a 'user' role to map back into the Java Servlet Context.  I see the SAML Request sent to keycloak and keycloak responds with a SAML Assertion using a POST.  However, I am unable to access the SAML Assertion using the Java Servlet that I have configured.

Java (web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                                                                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Simple</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>       
    </security-constraint>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AuthServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>AuthServlet</servlet-class>      
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AuthServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/saml</url-pattern>        
    </servlet-mapping>
    
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>simpleRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
    
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Java Servlet (AuthServlet.java):

```
public class AuthServlet extends HttpServlet {
    
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        this.getServletContext().log("POSTing");
        
        SamlPrincipal samlPrincipal = (SamlPrincipal) request.getUserPrincipal();
        samlPrincipal.getAttributeNames().forEach( attribute -> {
            String value = samlPrincipal.getAttribute(attribute);
            this.getServletContext().log("key: " + attribute + " value: " + value);
        });
                
    }

}
```

However, I never see anything in my logs about POSTing. I do see that I accessed the appropriate resource

```
172.26.66.136 - - [16/Mar/2021:10:32:12 -0400] "GET /simple HTTP/1.1" 302 -
172.26.66.136 - - [16/Mar/2021:10:32:13 -0400] "GET /simple/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3442
172.26.66.136 - G-0bbe42f7-d80e-4b47-8572-53acaa5c8979 [16/Mar/2021:10:32:18 -0400] "POST /simple/saml HTTP/1.1" 302 -
172.26.66.136 - G-0bbe42f7-d80e-4b47-8572-53acaa5c8979 [16/Mar/2021:10:32:18 -0400] "GET /simple/ HTTP/1.1" 200 222
```

However, I do not see anything in the output logs.

Any ideas!!???

Answer (score 0):

I am going to call this an oops because to fully implement this solution you do not need to implement a servlet that responds to the SAML POST. You simply access the SAML Assertion from your servlet, after a successful login/logout, using:

```
SamlPrincipal saml = request.getUserPrincipal();
```